# How to use the new Swift SDK to upload to S3 from macOS

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, macos

I'm using the new Swift SDK to upload files from macOS to S3.

1 - I'm using static credentials to create the client:

```
let credConfig = AWSCredentialsProviderStaticConfig(
    accessKey: "XX",
    secret: "YY",
    sessionToken: nil,
    shutDownCallback: nil
)

let config = try S3Client.S3ClientConfiguration(
    credentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider.fromStatic(credConfig),
    region: "eu-west-1"
)

let s3Client = S3Client(config: s3Config)
```

2 Then start the file upload

```
let body = try ByteStream.from(data: Data(contentsOf: fileURL))

s3.putObject(
    input: PutObjectInput(
        body: body,
        bucket: bucketName,
        key: "\(folder)/\(filename)"
    ),
    completion: { [unowned self] result in
        // Handling result here
    }
)
```

But, the application just get's stuck with 99% processor load and no files are uploaded. [Stack Trace is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pbu2Buw2eTM7sMAd_8Wd40a2kM9CDW8K/view?usp=sharing)

I appreciate that the SDk is new - but this seems like core functionality.

I have logged an issue on the project GitHub, but hoped someone might have come across this, or have a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the AWS SDK. It is still < v1

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-swift/issues/573

Instead, we switched to using Soto
https://github.com/soto-project/soto as an unofficial library

see the usage example in https://medium.com/macoclock/aws-s3-sdk-integration-using-swift-package-manager-for-ios-101bf783a4f0